# how to run coturn in ubuntu running on localhost

Tags: coturn

i want to run coturn server on ubuntu i do not have any domain i want to test it on localhost for that i followed a tutorial https://www.allerstorfer.at/install-coturn-on-ubuntu/
here are the steps i followed

```
sudo apt-get install coturn

nano /etc/default/coturn

TURNSERVER_ENABLED=1
listening-port=3478
cli-port=5766
listening-ip=172.17.19.101
```

created a secret

openssl rand -hex 32

and added to the turnserver.conf file

```
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=583bAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFF

vi /etc/services

stun-turn       3478/tcp                        # Coturn
stun-turn       3478/udp                        # Coturn
stun-turn-tls   5349/tcp                        # Coturn
stun-turn-tls   5349/udp                        # Coturn
turnserver-cli  5766/tcp                        # Coturn
```

started the coturn server

```
turnserver -o -v 

0: log file opened: /var/tmp/turn_18181_2020-09-15.log
0: 
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.5.0.7 'dan Eider'
0: 
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 65535
0: 
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 32500 (approximately)
0: 

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: DTLS 1.2 supported
0: TURN/STUN ALPN supported
0: Third-party authorization (oAuth) supported
0: GCM (AEAD) supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018 (0x1010100f)
0: 
0: SQLite supported, default database location is /var/lib/turn/turndb
0: Redis supported
0: PostgreSQL supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver.conf
0: Bad configuration format: TURNSERVER_ENABLED
0: Listener address to use: 172.17.19.101
0: Config file found: /etc/turnserver.conf
0: Bad configuration format: TURNSERVER_ENABLED
0: Domain name: 
0: Default realm: 
0: ERROR: 
CONFIG ERROR: Empty cli-password, and so telnet cli interface is disabled! Please set a non empty cli-password!
0: 
CONFIGURATION ALERT: you did specify the long-term credentials usage
 but you did not specify the default realm option (-r option).
        Check your configuration.
0: WARNING: cannot find certificate file: turn_server_cert.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because certificate file is not set properly
0: WARNING: cannot find private key file: turn_server_pkey.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because private key file is not set properly
0: Relay address to use: 0.0.0.0


netstat -npta | grep turnserver
```

8            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3478            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18889/turnserver

then

```
service coturn stop
service coturn start
service coturn restart
service coturn status
```

### returned

```
service coturn status
● coturn.service - LSB: coturn TURN Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/coturn; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-09-15 17:02:05 PKT; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18860 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/coturn stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18867 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/coturn start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 15 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/coturn.service
           └─18889 /usr/bin/turnserver -c /etc/turnserver.conf -o -v
```

there is a step given in the tutorial as

```
Add to DNS
turn.domain.xx → domain.xx
stun.domain.xx → domain.xx
```

i am confused on this part so i
edited /etc/hosts file and added

```
127.0.0.1   turn.domain.xx
127.0.0.1   sturn.domain.xx
```

and

```
telnet localhost 5766
```

returns

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

but in the tutorial it shows the output the only thing i have changed is the listening_ip which they used

```
listening-ip=172.17.19.101
```

and i used

```
listening-ip=0.0.0.0
```

if i use ->

```
listening-ip=172.17.19.101
```

then the command ->

```
netstat -npta | grep turnserver
```

returned nothing

please guide me how can i test the coturn server on localhost

Answer (score 1):

Even it seems a bit late; your `turnserver.conf` file has an invalid line `TURNSERVER_ENABLED=1`. This line corrupts your conf file and turnserver does not start. As you can see in the log file:

```
0: Bad configuration format: TURNSERVER_ENABLED
```

You can not use this parameter in the `turnserver.conf` file. This parameter is for `/etc/default/coturn` file.